# Google App engine, django, userena, database setup

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-users

I am trying to build a web app with GAE, Django. The user registration would be userena. I already use the django-nonrel and all the setup to get the first part working and I am trying to syncdb for userena. I am keep getting this errors, Could you please help me on this.

```
BB8265:epapyri-django$ sudo django-admin.py syncdb
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

settings.py and manage.py are in the same directory and I did not have this issue before adding this plugin.

the settings.py for database section is as follows:

```
# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['native'] = DATABASES['default']
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': 'native'}
AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    # social_auth
    'httplib2',
    'openid',
    'oauth2',
    'social_auth',
    #userena
    'userena',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'accounts',
    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)
```

and this is once I runserver

```
BB8265:epapyri-django$ sudo django-admin.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

[edited]

I remove the non django project from INSTALL_APP, import the django.models to my accounts/MyProfile, and chmod 777 on the .datastore since it shouldn't ask for permission every time modify it.

{`File "/git/ePapyri/epapyri-django/djangoappengine/db/base.py", line 160, in _value_for_db
    raise DatabaseError("Only strings and positive integers "
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Only strings and positive integers may be used as keys on GAE.`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `django-admin.py` to run syncdb and runserver? You should be using `manage.py`.

And you should definitely not be using `sudo` to run either of these.

(Also note your INSTALLED_APPS seems to be nonsense: it contains a whole lot of plain Python libraries like httplib2 and oauth2 which have no business at all being there.)

**Edited**

Firstly, you should have edited your question to add the traceback.

Secondly, the error message is very clear: you have not imported `django.db.models` in your accounts/models.py file.

Thirdly, it is still nonsense to include non-Django libraries in INSTALLED_APPS. There is simply no need to do so. And your datastore should not have been created with sudo in the first place - either delete and recreate it, or use `chmod` to make it accessible to a normal user.

Comment: Thanks for your respond Daniel, I appreciate it. I setup the django to use social-auth as well, some of those libraries are for that part. also since it works with a datastore, it always complain about the permission on .datastore file, that's why I used sudo. This is the message that I got after using manage.

Comment: also this is the linke that I follow for userena, http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html#required-settings

Comment: I found the problem. the django-nonrel does not support models.OneToOneField. that's why its complains about it, How could i fix it?

Comment: Thanks, I did chmod 777 on datasotore as you mentioned. I import the models and it does not complain about that any more, I appreciate your help. Now the issue is different Daniel. It is " django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Only strings and positive integers may be used as keys on GAE."

Comment: I find out the problem is adding a PIL to libraries in GAE, and yaml file would solve the issue, since it was complaining about image library in python.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem is solved by adding a PIL to libraries in GAE, and yaml file would solve the issue, since it was complaining about image library in python. the link to all supported libraries for django is https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27, so add all the needed libraries to .yaml file and to the INSTALL_APP.